# useEffect hook is running in loop and hanging the application

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

What I am building here is a simple todo application using hooks
with two input fields and one submit button. On submit I am saving the content of the inputs in an array and storing it in async storage. Using retrieve function I am fetching the values and displaying it below in a view component in list form.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // AsyncStorage.clear();
  retrieveData();
}, [data]);

const retrieveData = async () => {
  try {
    const valueString = await AsyncStorage.getItem("user");
    const value = JSON.parse(valueString);
    setData(value);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Removing the data element from the useEffect, doesn't update the component and the current value updated in the array is not displayed. It does get displayed only after another text is added in the array and the same goes on for the future addition to the data. But the app doesn't hang for sure.

Thanks for any help

Comment: pass empty array ```[]``` as a second parameter instead of ```[data]``` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Your `useEffect` hook will run any time `data` is changed. (As it is in the dependency list).

However, inside your `useEffect` you call `retrieveData` which calls `setData(value);`.

This will update `data`. Which in turn, will trigger `useEffect` again.

If you are wanting to just call `retrieveData` once on startup, you can empty the dependency list and it will act like `componentDidMount`.

Comment: Updating it as you said, leads to not rendering the component and gets updated on second submit.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `[data]` as second argument to useEffect which is dependency list.

That is the reason it is looping infinite. change it to [], it will run only once.

```
useEffect(() => {
    // AsyncStorage.clear();
    retrieveData();
  }, [data]);
```

Comment: Changing it to empty array doesn't update the component and the current value updated in the array is not displayed. It does gets displayed only after another text is added in the array and same goes on for future. But you are correct the app doesn't hang.

Comment: Good hear that, the hang is not happening. Can you update the full component code? it will help to understand why it not getting updated.